# Вылетает приложение KivyPython на android

Tags: android, python, kivy

Написал приложение для андроид на киви.На компьютере все работает, а при запуске на телефоне начинается заставка и все вылетает.

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.button import Button  
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout 
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.config import Config 
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
import pyperclip


Config.set("kivy","keyboard_mode","systemanddock")

def chan(b):
    global sp
    keys={'а':'@', 'и':'®', 'с':'¢', 'ь':'~','б':'¿', 'й':'©', 'т':'¦', 'ы':'¡','в':'?', 'к':'#', 'у':'¥', 'ъ':'~|',
'г':'[', 'л':'₽', 'ф':'=', 'э':'€','д':'^', 'м':':', 'ц':'+', 'ю':'>' ,'е':'%', 'н':'<', 'х':'×', 'я':'}','ё':'‰', 'о':'°', 'ч':'(', ' ':' ',
'ж':'¶', 'п':']', 'ш':'``','з':'§', 'р':'{', 'щ':'$',' ' : '   ', ".":".",",":","}
    crypt=""
    for i in b:
        if i in keys:
            crypt+=keys[i]
            sp=(crypt+"\n")
    return sp

def change(b):
    global sp
    keys={'@':'а', '®':'и', '¢':'с', '~':'ь','¿':'б', '©':'й', '¦':'т', '¡':'ы','?':'в', '#':'к', '¥':'у', '~|':'ъ',
'[':'г', '₽':'л', '=':'ф', '€':'э','^':'д', ':':'м', '+':'ц', '>':'ю' ,'%':'е', '<':'н', '×':'х', '}':'я','‰':'ё', '°':'о', '(':'ч', ' ':' ',
'¶':'ж', ']':'п', '``':'ш','§':'з', '{':'р', '$':'щ',' ' : '   ', ".":".",",":","}
    crypt=""
    for i in b:
        if i in keys:
            crypt+=keys[i]
            sp=(crypt+"\n")
    return sp


class Container(GridLayout):
    def clear(self):
        self.text_input.text=" "


    def copy(self):
        pyperclip.copy(self.text_input.text)

    def paste(self):
        self.text_input.text=pyperclip.paste()


    def change_text(self):
        mass=self.text_input.text

        result=chan(mass)

        self.text_input.text=result

    def change_text2(self):
        mass=self.text_input.text

        result=change(mass)

        self.text_input.text=result



class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return Container()

if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()

KV ФАЙЛ
<Container>:
    rows: 2
    text_input: text_input


    AnchorLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: text_input


    BoxLayout:


        size_hint: 0.3, 0.1
        Button:
            text:"Зашифровать"
            on_release:
                root.change_text()

        Button:
            text:"Стереть"

            on_release:
                root.clear()

        Button:
            text:"Расшифровать"

            on_release:
                root.change_text2()

        Button:
            text:"Копировать"

            on_release:
                root.copy()
        Button:
            text:"Вставить"

            on_release:
                root.paste()
```

Comment: Только методом тыка и исключения. Вероятно, какая-то либа подводит

Comment: Подключите телефон через adb, сервер adb запускайте через sudo, иначе телефон может быть unregistered. Раскомментируйте строку `android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D` в spec файле и запускайте команду `buildozer android debug deploy run logcat`. Это даст возможность увидеть в консоли все ошибки, может каких-то разрешений не хватает или библиотек.